# How to get the children data item of the selected node?

Tags: kendo-treeview

I'm trying to fetch the children data item of the selected node of a Kendo Treeview. I used this as my reference: http://www.telerik.com/forums/children-of-dataitem

Here are the excerpt of my code:

```
<ul id="fileTreeView">
</ul>

var fileTreeView = $("#fileTreeView").kendoTreeView({ template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()) }),
ftvData = fileTreeView.data('kendoTreeView'),
selectedNode = ftvData.select(),
items = ftvData.dataItem(selectedNode).children.data;
```

I assumed `e.node` from the link above has similar data type with the `ftvData.select()`. So when `selectedNode.hasChildren` is true, I expected that `items` has value but the `items.length` stays as 0.

Anyway, I'm just trying to prevent the creation of duplicate "folder".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `children.data` is just an empty shell. What works is `children._data`. Looks like it is a bug with version we're using: **telerik.ui.for.aspnetmvc.2015.1.408.commercial**